# Android export browser history as JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I wrote a simple android app to export the browsers history as JSON,  but I do not know if the resulting JSON is a format that the user will easily be able to parse and use.

Is there any way that i could improve the resulting format?  Will it be easy for the user to use?

I have the title of the page first, should I have the URL first instead?

The URL contains escape characters, but this does not work in all browsers, For example Chrome can reformat the url but Safari can't. Is there a way to fix this so the URL will work in all browsers?

Here is the code for the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getBrowserHist();
    }

    public void getBrowserHist() {
        try {
            JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();

            String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
                    Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE,
                    Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS };
            String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0";
            Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    proj, sel, null, null);
            mCur.moveToFirst();
            if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
                boolean cont = true;
                while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    String title = mCur.getString(mCur
                            .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
                    String url = mCur.getString(mCur
                            .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
                    String date = mCur.getString(mCur
                            .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE));
                    String visits = mCur.getString(mCur
                            .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS));
                    jsonObject.put("TITLE", title);
                    jsonObject.put("URL", url);
                    jsonObject.put("DATE", date);
                    jsonObject.put("VISITS", visits);

                    parent.put(title, jsonObject);
                    mCur.moveToNext();
                }
                EditText output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outputArea);
                output.setText(parent.toString(4));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copy);
        copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outputArea);
                String data = output.getText().toString();
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", data);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
        });

        Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outputArea);
                String data = output.getText().toString();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the resulting JSON.

```
{
   "Academia Stack Exchange": {
       "DATE": "1388375986375",
       "URL": "http:\/\/academia.stackexchange.com\/",
       "VISITS": "1",
       "TITLE": "Academia Stack Exchange"
   },
   "ProgrammableWeb: Subscribe": {
       "DATE": "1388307236378",
       "URL": "http:\/\/www.programmableweb.com\/pwtsubscribe",
       "VISITS": "1",
       "TITLE": "ProgrammableWeb: Subscribe"
   },
   "Bitcoin Block Explorer - Blockchain.info": {
       "DATE": "1388306500160",
       "URL": "http:\/\/blockchain.info\/",
       "VISITS": "1",
       "TITLE": "Bitcoin Block Explorer - Blockchain.info"
   },
      "All Sites - Stack Exchange": {
       "DATE": "1388375962623",
       "URL": "http:\/\/stackexchange.com\/sites",
       "VISITS": "1",
       "TITLE": "All Sites - Stack Exchange"
   },
   "Block Explorer API - blockchain.info": {
       "DATE": "1388306537030",
       "URL": "http:\/\/blockchain.info\/api\/blockchain_api",
       "VISITS": "3",
       "TITLE": "Block Explorer API - blockchain.info"
   },
   "ProgrammableWeb: Subscribe Success": {
       "DATE": "1388307257562",
       "URL": "http:\/\/www.programmableweb.com\/pwtsubscribesuccess",
       "VISITS": "2",
       "TITLE": "ProgrammableWeb: Subscribe Success"
   },
   "http:\/\/blockchain.info\/rawaddr\/1CuJxwjqf8z2uy3EHh2Kge12tcR5eNiB4t": {
       "DATE": "1388306616394",
       "URL": "http:\/\/blockchain.info\/rawaddr\/1CuJxwjqf8z2uy3EHh2Kge12tcR5eNiB4t",
       "VISITS": "1",
       "TITLE": "http:\/\/blockchain.info\/rawaddr\/1CuJxwjqf8z2uy3EHh2Kge12tcR5eNiB4t"
   },
    "Code Review Stack Exchange": {
       "DATE": "1388376002575",
       "URL": "http:\/\/codereview.stackexchange.com\/",
       "VISITS": "1",
       "TITLE": "Code Review Stack Exchange"
   },
    "Stack Overflow": {
       "DATE": "1388375977992",
       "URL": "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/?as=1",
       "VISITS": "1",
       "TITLE": "Stack Overflow"
   }
}
```

Here is the [repository](https://github.com/kylelk/BrowserHistory) for the app.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is in-topic. We do *code* reviews, not suggestions on how to make an *output format* better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the JSON to be easily parsed, I would suggest using a JSONArray so your output is ordered the way it is in the browsers history (unlike the JSONObject, which are key/value pairs not in order). If you use JSONArray you should save the title inside the objects of course.

---

If you want to have it human readable, how about exporting it as `.pdf` or `.html` file with clickable links.

---

If you want to do some more work, you could use the jsondata, export it as your own data-format, and build an Activity for reading and displaying this data to make it human readable.

You could easily un-escape the URLs, then they should work in every browser.

---

Small code correction: your variable `cont` in line 37 should be obsolete.